# The Script Keeps adding the new log file content to the previous log file. How to stop it?

Tags: powershell

I want the below powershell script to generate a new log file when it runs every time and it works. But now the problem is not only does it generates a new file, but it adds the content of the latest file to the previously generated log file.

Could you please help me to stop that?

The script is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$inactiveDays = 40
$disableDaysInactive=(Get-Date).AddDays(-($inactiveDays))
$todaysDate = (Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd_HH-mm-ss")


$LogFile = "C:\temp\Test\Disabled_and_Moved_User_Accounts_$todaysDate.log"
$DisabledOU = 'OU=Test Disable,OU=User Accounts,OU=Car,DC=car,DC=com'
$path= "OU=Test,OU=User Accounts,OU=Car,DC=car,DC=com"
 

$userlist = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $path -Filter {(Enabled -eq $True)} -Properties * | Where-Object {($_.description -Notlike "*Service Account*") -and ($_.lastLogonDate -lt $disableDaysInactive) -and ($_.lastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} 

Start-Transcript -path $LogFile

if ($userlist) {    

ForEach ($user in $userlist){        
$desc = "Disabled on $(Get-Date) - Inactive for 40 Days $($user.Description)"         

try {            
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description $desc -Enabled $false            
Move-ADObject -Identity $user -TargetPath $DisabledOU 
Write-Output $user.DisplayName
}        
catch {            
'Error occured updating account {0}. {1}' -f $user.SamAccountName, $_        }     }}
else {    "The existing users in 'User Accounts' are active within last 40 days"

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect your issue is that you haven't got a `Stop-Transcript` statement at the end of your code to close it off, so the previous transcript session is still running even if a new one is started later.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is the issue. I forgot to add the stop-script. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. It solved the problem.